# "syntax error near unexpected token `(' " when deleting all files(s) or directory(s) using rm command with an exception

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, gitlab-ci, nfs

```
$ sshpass -p "$SSH_PASS" ssh student@"$IP_NFS" "sudo rm -r /srv/nfs4/share/assets_prod/!(v$TAG)"
Warning: Permanently added 'x.x.x.x' (ED0599) to the list of known hosts.
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 0: `sudo rm -r /srv/nfs4/share/assets_prod/!(v0.0.3-rc6)'
```

The results of checking directly to the nfs server

```
student@nfs:~$ sudo echo rm -r /srv/nfs4/share/assets_prod/!(v0.0.3-rc6)
rm -r /srv/nfs4/share/assets_prod/kk.dd /srv/nfs4/share/assets_prod/kk.dkk /srv/nfs4/share/assets_prod/kk.dkkff /srv/nfs4/share/assets_prod/v0.0.3-rc2 /srv/nfs4/share/assets_prod/v0.0.3-rc3 /srv/nfs4/share/assets_prod/v0.0.3-rc4 /srv/nfs4/share/assets_prod/v0.0.3-rc5
```

What is causing the command to have problems running?

Comment: as it says "sudo rm -r /srv/nfs4/share/assets_prod/!(v0.0.3-rc6)" is causing the error, the ( shouldnt be there. Did you double check if that file exists? or is it a directory?

Comment: I've checked it directly to the NFS server and the result is normal but somehow it gets an error when running it via gitlab-ci `student@nfs:~$ sudo echo rm -r /srv/nfs4/share/assets_prod/!(v0.0.3-rc6)
rm -r /srv/nfs4/share/assets_prod/kk.dd /srv/nfs4/share/assets_prod/kk.dkk /srv/nfs4/share/assets_prod/kk.dkkff /srv/nfs4/share/assets_prod/v0.0.3-rc2 /srv/nfs4/share/assets_prod/v0.0.3-rc3 /srv/nfs4/share/assets_prod/v0.0.3-rc4 /srv/nfs4/share/assets_prod/v0.0.3-rc5`

Answer (score 0):

The remote end is really running

```
bash -c 'sudo rm -r /srv/nfs4/share/assets_prod/!(v$TAG)'
```

and the `extglob` option that is set for your *interactive* shell is not set for the non-interactive shell invoked by `bash -c`.

```
sshpass -p "$SSH_PASS" ssh student@"$IP_NFS" "shopt -s extglob; sudo rm -r /srv/nfs4/share/assets_prod/!(v$TAG)"
```

should work.

Update: because `extglob` affects parsing, it must be enabled before the command line is parsed, but `x; y` is complete parsed before `x` is executed. Perhaps the following will work:

```
sshpass -p "$SSH_PASS" ssh student@"$IP_NFS" \
  "bash -O extglob -c 'sudo rm -r /srv/nfs4/share/assets_prod/!(v$TAG)'"
```

If not (or even if it does), you can use `find`:

```
sshpass -p "$SSH_PASS" ssh student@"$IP_NFS" \
  find /srv/nfs4/share/assets_prod \! -name "v$TAG"
```

If that lists the files you want to delete, you can add `-delete` (if your `find` supports it) or `-exec rm {} +` to the `find` command to actually delete them.

Comment: Still have same problem `bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 0: `shopt -s extglob; sudo rm -rv /srv/nfs4/share/assets_prod/!(v0.0.3-rc9)'`

Comment: Oh, right. `extglob` affects parsing, and the entire line is parsed before `shopt` is actually executed.

Answer (score 0):

You have used the following command:

```
sudo rm -r /srv/nfs4/share/assets_prod/!(v$TAG)
```

but the parenthesis has a special meaning to the shell.  You had better to use

```
$ sshpass -p "$SSH_PASS" ssh student@"$IP_NFS" "sudo rm -r '/srv/nfs4/share/assets_prod/!(v$TAG)'"
```

to pass the literal string to `rm`, with no shell interference.